# Getting message - Read NVMe Identify Controller failed: NVME_IOCTL_ADMIN_CMD: Bad address - when using smartctl command

Tags: linux, bash, knoppix, smartctl

I am trying to check certain specifications of a hard drive on a computer with no operating system installed. I am using a Knoppix bootable disk (v8.6.1) to run a bash script with the line

```
smartctl -i /dev/nvme0
```

However, I keep getting the same message:

> Read NVMe Identify Controller failed: NVME_IOCTL_ADMIN_CMD: Bad address

I can run this command just fine on another computer (same model) with a different linux distribution already installed, but for some reason the command fails when running on the Knoppix disk.

Note: I can run commands like

```
smartctl -d nvme --scan
```

which outputs

> /dev/nvme0 -d nvme # /dev/nvme0, NVMe device

but I cannot run smartctl commands such as

```
smartctl -i /dev/nvme0
smartctl -x /dev/nvme0
smartctl -a /dev/nvme0
smartctl -H /dev/nvme0
```

or any other command that should actually return information about the hard drive. They all produce the same "bad address" message stated above.

Answer (score 1):

Knoppix historically shipped a 32-bit userspace and an optional 64-bit kernel. The changelog for Linux Kernel 5.6.8 includes a commit that specifically tackled the usage of NVME_IOCTL_ADMIN_CMD ioctls from a 32-bit smartctl on a 64-bit kernel (ref: https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/ChangeLog-5.6.8 commit 51750ad35f266751e14d6c7e8839b85c8069e27f). Moreover, Knoppix 8.6.1 shipped with Linux Kernel 5.3.5 (reference: https://www.knopper.net/knoppix/knoppix861-en.html. That's significantly before the patch landed, so it'd cause this type of error.

So, you've got two solutions:

1. upgrade to kernel 5.6.8 or higher so that the compat interface zeroes out the upper bits.
2. Rebuild smartctl and its dependencies for 64-bit.